# Why is 地 in 慢慢地走?

Tags: particles

I just read about all the three "de" in Chinese (的，得，地) here in this website :

https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Structural_particle_%22de%22

In the 地's section, it's said that if you use a "straight-up" adverb, you don't need to use 地 at all.

Yet there's this one example sentence which left me confused :

> 慢慢地走

Means : slowly walk.

Now, the question is :

1)

> If my memory serves me right, isn't 慢慢 already an adverb that means "slowly"? If that's so, then why in that sentence, 地 is still used after 慢慢?

2)

> Plus, if this 慢慢 word turns out to be an exception (like, even though 慢慢 itself is already an adverb, I still need to use 地), is there any other exceptions beside 慢慢?

Thank you!!!

Comment: users note that the examples in the link including ＂慢慢＂ are disyllabic, monosyllabic (straight-up ?) adverbs
usually are not followed by 地，for when to use or not to use 地 see more comprehensive grammars and/or search this site (has been considered more than once at this site)

Comment: @user6065 I didn't know about that disyllabic and monosyllabic thing before  thank you for telling me that ☺️

Comment: searching site for relevant info about 地 has resulted in: chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/13776/… (esp. comment #1) chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/21893/… (esp. comment #1) site rule: avoid thanking users

Comment: @user6065 Well, but they (and you) have helped me, so I think, at least, I need to thank you guys 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some adverbs require the adverb marker '地' and some don't. As you stated, '慢慢' can be applied directly before a verb without adding '地'

Look at the following two forms:

> "**慢慢**走" (walk **slowly**) simply describe the action, the focus in on the verb "走" (walk), "慢慢" is the additional information that describe how the verb is carried out.
>
> "**慢慢地**走" (walk **in a slow manner**) emphasize the adverb, the focus is on the manner/degree of the verb

It applies to other adverbs that do not need the adverb marker '地' too

Example:

急急逃走 - run away hurriedly

急急地逃走 - run away in a hurried manner

用力打 - hit forcefully

用力地打 - hit with a forceful degree

輕輕撫摸 - gently stroke

輕輕地撫摸 - stroke in a gentle manner/ stroke in a light degree