# Is 地 missing in 学校希望每个学生都能自由发展?

Tags: grammar

In this sentence "学校希望每个学生都能自由发展"， 自由 is an adjective and 发展 is a verb. Why isn't "地" used as "自由地发展"? Thank you!

Comment: See my answer to this question  https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/32388/why-is-%e5%9c%b0-in-%e6%85%a2%e6%85%a2%e5%9c%b0%e8%b5%b0

Comment: The answer to [Why can 地 sometimes be omitted when placed after adjectives?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/40528/8099) might help with this question.

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct. "地" is omitted but not missed.

Comment: Could you please explain, why 地 is omitted in this case? Thank you!

Comment: Just habit. We often omit "的" and "地".

Answer (score 1):

学校希望每个学生都能自由发展。
school hope every student all can free develop
Our school hopes each student will be able to freely unfold their abilities.

If 自由 is an adjective, then wouldn't you rather use 的？自由的发展？

According to Western Grammar, adjectives describe nouns, thus, 发展 should be a noun, n'est pas?

What I'm trying to say is: Chinese is not English. You cannot just think, "Western Grammar is unreservedly applicable here." That would be Anglosaxon arrogance!

Comment: In English, it would be "freely develop" not "free develop". "Develop" is a verb, just like 发展 is a verb not a noun (发展 can be used as a noun, but that's not the case here). Therefore, we use 自由地 (freely, adverb) but not 自由的 (free, adjective). In this case the grammar rules between the two languages actually do not differ that much.

Answer (score 1):

学校希望每个学生都能"**自由发展**"。Here "自由发展" is a 四字詞/片語, usually used as a slogan to emphasis the intention of allowing every student to "free develop and expand", or "develop and expand freely" (自由的/地发展).

A similar and often seen 四字詞/片語 is "自由戀愛".